# Profile table not being created for extended User model in django

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am facing this problem in django where even though there is a Profile model in my models.py file which extends the django User model still on running the 'makemigration' and 'migrate' commands the Profile table is not being generated in database.

This is my models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clg_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    enrollment_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True, blank=False)
    clg_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)

class Result(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sem = models.IntegerField()
    exam_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    percnt = models.FloatField(null=True)
    cgpa = models.FloatField(null=True)

class Marks(models.Model):
    result = models.ForeignKey(Result, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    course_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    course_credit = models.IntegerField(null=True)    
    grade = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

Here is the output of **py manage.py makemigration account**:

```
Migrations for 'account':
  account\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Result
    - Create model Profile
    - Create model Marks
```

And this is the output of **py manage.py migrate**:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with your account app . but you can solve it with  :

1-  delete ***`__pycache__`*** and **`migrations`**  folders located inside account app

2 - run `python manage.py makemigrations account  zero`

3 - then run `python manage.py makemigrations account`

4 - finally run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: It didnt worked still there isnt an account_profile table in database.

Comment: that's weird ! please run `python manage.py migrate --fake account zero` then  `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate account 0001`

Comment: Dont know whats not working it still not creating the table. Also the last command is giving me "account_student" already existing error

Comment: I solved the problem. I dropped the database and deleted the migration file and again created the database now its working fine

Comment: Great  ! Add your solution as answer to help other getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved the following error by just dropping the whole Database and deleting the py_cache and migration files of my application. Just create another database and rerun the migration and migrate commands. Hope this helps.